# Unable to solve validation error

Tags: jquery

in jQuery i tried:

```
$('#imgAdd').live("click", function() {
    if ($('#txtName').val() == "") {
        $('#lblError').show();
        $('#lblError').text() = "Please enter a  Name";
        $('#txtMenuName').focus();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but i got a error in console.

> invalid assignment left-hand side
>   $('#lblError').text() = "Please enter a Menu Name";

I also want if text is entered in field automatically `lblerror` is hide. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#lblError').text("Please enter a Menu Name");
```

`text()` function is both a **getter** and a **setter** function. Thus, if you call it without parameters, you **get** the current text of the HTML element. But if you pass a parameter to it, you **set** the text of the HTML element.

For hiding the error message, when user enters text into textbox, you can use `keyup` event handler of jQuery:

```
$('#txtName').keyup(function(e){
   if($(this).val().length > 0) {
       $('#lblError').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Any idea about hide `lebel` when text is entered in `textbox`.Thanks.